# Is it possible to redirect unauthorized users to login page via web.config?(everything else failed)

Tags: asp.net-webpages

The IIS server keeps redirecting me to wrong urls when anonymous users try to access pages for authorized users.
This is what I found:

Link to rewrite module, but I was unable to find what I needed:
http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#String_functions

Answer (score 0):

I experimented a bit and got it to work when I changed the url to match the wrong path "`Account/Login`":

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules> 
         <rule name="Unauthorized access" stopProcessing="true">
           <match url="Account/Login" />
           <action type="Redirect" url="/Login.aspx"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

Now it's not only redirecting to "`Login.aspx`" but it also has the original query string: `Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fManagerPages%2fVideoManager.aspx`